# plotting estimates for binomial glm using sjplot in r

Tags: r

I am trying to use sjplot to create html tables for output for a glm (actually a mixed effects model, but I will keep it simple), and I can't figure out how to print estimates and se for predictors. Here is an example:

```
n <- 50
cov <- 10
x <- c(rep(0,n/2), rep(1, n/2))
p <- 0.4 + 0.2*x
y <- rbinom(n, cov, p)

ggplot(data.frame(x=factor(x),y=as.numeric(y)), 
       aes(x=x, y=y/cov)) +
  geom_point(position=position_jitter(height=0.02, width=0.07)) +
  xlab("x") + 
  ylab("y/cov") 


model0 <- glm(cbind(y, cov-y) ~ x, family="binomial")
summary(model0)

tab_model(model0,show.est = TRUE)
```

As you can see in the results, tab_model() doesn't print the estimates, only the odd ratio and CI for the odd ratio. Is it possible to do this in sjplot, or should I look elsewhere. I am basically just wanting to put the table into an rmarkdown, but find it to be a little more tricky than I expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include the argument `transform = NULL` to prevent `tab_model` from automatically exponentiating the estimates into odds ratios:

```r
tab_model(model0, transform = NULL, show.est = TRUE, show.se = TRUE)
```

[image]